# mutate data frame if records are duplicate with other data frame

Tags: r

I have two data frames and have two ids columns, now i want to validate if id1 in df1 available in df2 id2  the mutate new column to duplicate exist but my code is not working what is am doing wrong ..??

also i am giving user a input parameter to give column names to be validated

```
df1 <-  data.frame(ID1= c("EMT1","EMT2","EMT3","EMT4","EMT5","EMT6","EMT7","EMT8","EMT9","EMT10","EMT11","EMT12","EMT13","EMT14","EMT15","EMT16","EMT17","EMT18","EMT19","EMT20","EMT21","EMT22","EMT23","EMT24","EMT25","EMT25","EMT27"))
df2 <-  data.frame(ID2= c("EMT10","EMT10","EMT10","EMT8","EMT8","EMT8","EMT6","EMT10","EMT6","","EMT6","EMT6","EMT5","EMT5","EMT5","EMT5","EMT5","EMT5","EMT5","EMT4","EMT4","EMT4","EMT4","EMT23","EMT32","EMT241","EMT51"))

empid_new = "ID1"
empid_old = "ID2"


uniqu_emp <- df2 %>% select(empid_old) %>% distinct()
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(`dupe id` = ifelse((df1[[empid_new]] %in% uniqu_emp)== TRUE, "duplicate exist",""))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `dplyr` you can refer the dataframe with `.data`.

`distinct` returns a dataframe to compare with `%in%` you need a vector.

```
library(dplyr)
uniqu_emp <- df2 %>% distinct(.data[[empid_old]]) %>% pull()

df1 %>% 
   mutate(`dupe id` = ifelse(.data[[empid_new]] %in% uniqu_emp, 
                       "duplicate exist",""))

#     ID1         dupe id
#1   EMT1                
#2   EMT2                
#3   EMT3                
#4   EMT4 duplicate exist
#5   EMT5 duplicate exist
#6   EMT6 duplicate exist
#7   EMT7                
#8   EMT8 duplicate exist
#9   EMT9                
#10 EMT10 duplicate exist
#11 EMT11                
#12 EMT12   
#....             
#....
```

Comment: if first cell of my  df1 will always be blank then there will b any issue with that...?
i am asking this because in my original data frame this is still not working i have checked everything like space etc all ok 
only the thing is my first cell in blank (NA) in DF1

Comment: I don't think anything will change if the first value is `NA` or blank. This should work the same. Did you assign the result back to the data `df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(\`dupe id\`....`  ? Also what do you mean by doesn't work? Any error message or incorrect output? Does it work as expected for the data you have shared?

Comment: yes i assign the result back to data.
actually not showing any error but the mutate column in showing as blank not showing any duplicates. what can be a reason
i also checked the  class (character) is same

Comment: Check if there are any whitespaces. Do `df1[] <- lapply(df1, trimws)` and `df2[] <- lapply(df2, trimws)` to remove them and try the answer again. Can you provide an example where we can reproduce this error?

Comment: no spaces have checked already. data frame is very big thats why i tried to have with example in my question.

Comment: Does the answer work as expected for the example shared?

Comment: yes it is working for the same correctly but for my actual database why not its working , what can be a reason...??

Comment: Hmm...not sure about it. Maybe if you can share some rows of your actual dataset on which we can reproduce the wrong results that would be helpful to debug.